# Issue with a completion handler called inside a closure

Tags: swift, closures

I've found often snippets like the code below, in which a `NSPersistentContainer` is initialised in a closure and assigned to a variable.

However I don't think this code is optimal as the completion handler of the function `loadPersistentStores` is not executed synchronously with the rest of the code.

Which means the `storeDescription` could not be available right after creating the container in the next line of code. Correct? If so, what could be an elegant solution?

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Test")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't lazy instantiate the persistentContainer but just do it earlier.
2. Include the dependent line of code in the completion handler as well.
3. Something with a store-is-ready-bool which I dont like personally.
4. Leave it as is, if its not generating issues.

Comment: I see. I have a question about point 3: if you dont like personally this solution, why do you suggest it? :) Is there something better? (I also don't like it)

Comment: Its a very easy solution and its unfair to not suggest it because an 'elegant solution' is just preference. I have used the CoreData template a couple of times and never ran in to a problem with that lazily instantiated persistantContainer, I would suggest to just leave it like that if its not a problem.